# Using a lower pot value for motor bidirectional controller

Tags: resistors, 555, potentiometer, motor-controller

I'm looking to make a bidirectional motor controller. I would like to use the following diagram. What values should the resistors be in order to use pot(S) of smaller value than 100k and the circuit still work? 
Can someone please explain the formula when using different pots value.
[image: circuit]

Comment: Why don't you use a simple H-bridge motor driver IC to drive the motor in both direction.  Something similar to a NCV7702B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinarily you could just scale the resistors and capacitor and it would work, but 1K is about as low as you should go with R1.

What you can do is to transfer some of the resistance in R3 into R1.

So, for example, to use 10K pots you could reduce R3 to zero (short), leave R1 at 1K, reduce R2 to 1K, and increase C1 to 1000uF.

For 20K pots, R3= 1K, R1 = 1K, R2 = 2K, C1 = 470uF.

...and so on. I woukd not suggest going much lower than 10K.

---

The reasoning behind this is that the capacitor charges through R1+R3+R5, but discharges through R2+R4. To keep the times similar to the original circuit you want the products of the total resistances and C1 to be the same as in the original circuit. You should be able to verify that my numbers are correct.

Answer (score 0):

The basic timing formula is given on page 11 of the [NE555 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf). Your circuit complicates matters slightly due to diodes D1 and D2, which steer the charge and discharge current through 2 different pots to give independent adjustment of ON and OFF times.

C1 charges from 1/3 to 2/3 of the power supply voltage through R1, D1, R3 and R5. If it wasn't for the voltage drop across D1 you could simply add all the resistor values and the timing formula would be T<sub>ON</sub> = 0.693 * C1 * (R1+R3+R5).

C1 discharges from 2/3 to 1/3 of the supply voltage through D2, R4 and R2, so (again ignoring diode voltage drop) the formula is T<sub>OFF</sub> = 0.693 * C1 * (R2+R4).

The diodes drop about 0.6V so these calculations will be off by about 10%. However this small error may not be significant in practice, especially since electrolytic capacitors often have >20% tolerance. Also since diode voltage drop is relatively constant it affects the absolute timing calculations but won't have much effect on adjusting the other components to match different pot resistances.

If you reduce pot resistance then to get the same timing you must increase the value of C1 by the same proportion. R2 and R3 'pad out' the pot resistances to give minimum ON and OFF times when the pots are turned to zero resistance, so they should also be reduced by the same proportion. For example if you change the pots from 100k to 10k then you should change C1 to 1000uF, and R2 and R3 to 1k each.

To get equal ON and OFF timimg R1 needs to be much smaller than R2 or R3. However it must not be *too* low or the current draw during discharge will be too high. For example at 100Ω it would draw 12V/100Ω = 0.12A and dissipate 12V * 0.12A = 1.44W (the maximum OFF/ON ratio that can be set is ~90% so the maximum *average* current and power in R1 would be ~90% of these figures). If R1 is a 0.5W resistor the minimum safe value would be about 500Ω, which limits the minimum practical pot resistance to 50K (unless you are willing to accept some difference between ON and OFF times).